# Variadic Function template not playing nice with std::function as argument

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to create a thread-safe `std::map` wrapper.
To avoid data-loss scenarios at the risk of misuse causing a resynchronization of the threads, I'm trying to implement a function into that wrapper that can operate directly on the internal `std::map` instance without breaking the `std::lock_guard`'s scope.
I had this working as expected a couple hours ago, but decided to change the function's definition to use `std::function` from `<functional>` instead, because some of those operations are so short they would be better run from a lambda.

I was hoping you guys can tell me what I'm doing wrong. I believe it has to do with the variadic templating of the function, because eliminating that and defining the function without it produces a functioning example.

**Old, Working Format:**

```
template <class T, class U, class V = std::less<T>> class Map {
    std::map<T,U,V> MAP;
    mutable std::mutex LOCK;
public:
    template <class... Args>
    void performOperation(void(*funct)(std::map<T,U,V>&, Args&...), Args&... args){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk (LOCK);
        funct(MAP, args...);
    }
};

Map<int, std::string> TSMap;

void functionThatDoesStuff(std::map<int, std::string>& tsm, const int& k, const std::string& v){
    //doStuff
}

int memberFunctionOfAnotherClass(const int& key, const std::string& val){
    TSMap.performOperation(functionThatDoesStuff, key, val);
}
```

**Working, non-variadic:**

```
template <class T, class U, class V = std::less<T>> class Map {
    std::map<T,U,V> MAP;
    mutable std::mutex LOCK;
public:
    void performOperation(std::function<void (std::map<T,U,V>&)> funct){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk (LOCK);
        funct(MAP);
    }
};

Map<int, std::string> TSMap;

int memberFunctionOfAnotherClass(const int& key, const std::string& val){
    TSMap.performOperation([](std::map<int, std::string>& tsm){
        //doStuff
    });
}
```

**New, broken format:**

```
template <class T, class U, class V = std::less<T>> class Map {
    std::map<T,U,V> MAP;
    mutable std::mutex LOCK;
public:
    template <class... Args>
    void performOperation(std::function<void (std::map<T,U,V>&, Args...)> funct, Args&... args){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk (LOCK);
        funct(MAP, args...);
    }
};

Map<int, std::string> TSMap;

int memberFunctionOfAnotherClass(const int& key, const std::string& val){
//  I have tried every different combination of const and ampersand-based referencing here to no avail
//                                                             v      v
    TSMap.performOperation([](std::map<int, std::string>& tsm, int k, std::string v){
        //doStuff
    }, key, val);
}
```

The error produced by the third code block is:

```
no instance of function template "Map<T,U,V>::performOperation [with T=int, U=std::string, V=std::less<int>]" matches the argument list
argument types are: (lambda []void (std::map<int, std::string, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::string>>> &tsm, int k, std::string v)->void, const int, const std::string)
object type is: Map<int, std::string, std::less<int>>
```

Comment: Your lambda is captureless; it works fine with a function pointer.

Comment: The template parameters cannot be deduced because lambda is not std:: function (no conversion occurs at this stage). Try suppressing the deduction of everything in the first function parameter (wrap std:: function with something like template<class T>struct suppress{using type=T;};)

Comment: @chris I was under the impression that passing the lambda with captures would attempt to run the lambda in place instead of passing it as an argument. The ``New Broken Format`` also refuses to work when handing it a function pointer as I did with the ``Old Working Format``.

Comment: @IgorR. Perhaps by adding a second template class to replace the std::function object and just do a typecheck in ``performOperation`` to make sure the passed object is a valid function pointer/lambda? Like ``template <class F, class... Args> void performOperation(F funct, Args&... args){``? It just doesn't seem safe...

Comment: No sure why it isn't safe. If you're ok with passing any callable - this is the way to go.  OTOH, if you need it to be std:: function, you have to suppress the type-deduction

Comment: @IgorR. If you could provide an example of the type-deduction suppression as a formal answer, I'd love to give you the rep for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's reduce your example to the following:

```
#include <functional>

template <class T>
void bad_foo(std::function<void(T)>, T)
{}

int main() {
   bad_foo([](int){}, 1);
}
```

When the compiler specializes `bad_foo` function template, it attempts to deduce the types of the template parameters, based on the arguments you pass to the function.

The both parameters are in a "deduced context", so the compiler tries to deduce the both. Although it is able to deduce `T` from the second argument, the deduction fails for the first one - because lambda is not `std::function`.  Note that the compiler does not perform any conversions at this stage!

The most simple way to work around this issue is to put the first parameter in a [non-deducible context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

[Like this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1qoWE12Jsa7s8cRi):

```
#include <functional>

template <class T>
struct undeduce {
    using type = T;
};

template <class T>
using undeduce_t = typename undeduce<T>::type;

template <class T>
void good_foo(undeduce_t<std::function<void(T)>>, T)
{}

int main() {
   good_foo([](int){}, 1);
}
```

As a side note, there is a very common real-life example, which demonstrates nearly the same problem. Think why wouldn't the following code compile, and how to fix it :-).

```
 #include <numeric>
 #include <vector>

 int main() {
     std::max(std::vector<int>{}.size(), 1); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

After having spent the last few hours fiddling with the issue, I couldn't figure out how Igor R's suggestion to suppress the type deduction should be implemented, and wasn't content with the idea of suppressing errors, I started testing other options.

It turns out I had a perfectly good answer when I posted this question. I still can't figure out why the templating breaks the function, but it has built and worked as expected to combine the first and second examples for something like the following:

```
template <class T, class U, class V = std::less<T>> class Map {
    std::map<T,U,V> MAP;
    mutable std::mutex LOCK;
public:
    template <class... Args>
    void performOperation(void(*funct)(std::map<T,U,V>&, Args&...), Args&... args){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk (LOCK);
        funct(MAP, args...);
    }

    bool performOperation(std::function<bool (std::map<T,U,V>&)> funct){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk (LOCK);
        return funct(MAP);
    }
};

Map<int, std::string> TSMap;

void functionThatDoesStuff(std::map<int, std::string>& tsm, const int& k, const std::string& v){
    //doStuff
}

int memberFunctionOfAnotherClass(const int& key, const std::string& val){
    TSMap.performOperation(functionThatDoesStuff, key, val);
    TSMap.performOperation([&](std::map<int, std::string>& tsm)->bool{
        //doStuff, key and val are available
        return true;
    });
}
```

It wasn't necessary to change to a boolean return on the lambda, I just wanted it in my implementation. This setup works just fine for me.